# Regex para hacer replace de caracteres específicos dentro de paréntesis (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Necesito hacer un replace con regex de caracteres especificos dentro de los parentesis el caso de ejemplo seria el siguiente string
color:rgba(218;7;7;056);font-size:25px;font-family:

solo seria cambiar los ";" (punto y coma) que estan dentro de los parentesis por comas ","
lo intente de la siguiente manera `titleconfrecoma.replace(/(([\;]+))/, ",")` y me devuelve como resultado color:rgba(218,7;7;056);font-size:25px;font-family: . pero si le agrego `titleconfrecoma.replace(/(([\;]+))/g, ",")` me altera todos los ";" no solo los que estan dentro del parentesis

Answer (score 0):

listo para quien lo necesite lo hice de la siguiente manera
 `var titleconfrecoma = "rgba(218;7;7;056);font-size:25px;font-family:";
var res = titleconfrecoma.substring(parseInt(titleconfrecoma.indexOf("(")), parseInt(titleconfrecoma.indexOf(")"))+1);
var resAux = res;
res = res.replace(/;/g, ",");
 res = titleconfrecoma.replace(resAux, res);`